# Google Chrome Extension Review Time process

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How much time will it take for Google to finish its review for a extension before it gets published to the Chrome Web Store?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Review times vary; some reviews complete in a few hours, others take many days, and in some cases a review can take several weeks

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-listing-108

Edit 08.01.2024
It seems that Google has slightly reorganised its portal.

> In some instances, a manual review is required, especially when
> sensitive permissions are requested. For this reason, review times
> and/or approval times can take longer

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/check-review

Comment: The link above shows a 404 as of today

Comment: @ZeMoon Seems they fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Long time no review, many days, few weeks. Our users can't wait. This is reason why we moved almost feature of extension from Chrome Extension to our own app

Comment: Do you still use your own server for serving chrome extensions?

Comment: @rbansal i moved almost key features to web. Now only some small feature on CHrome Extension. Google review app too slow even i used manifest v3. They said V3 will review faster and this is a lie

Comment: Manifest 3 is also slow in review. Did you try self-hosting the extension? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Gg has stopped support self-hosting

Answer (score 0):

So it's weird.  The review now take 10 days because they review all versions like its new. So if you make a push and have a small fix it's another 10 days.  And sometimes it is more than 10 days.

This means a different strategy towards trying to get your extension deployed. First we are setting up a testing item in the Chrome Store Dev Section so that we can test our extension extensively in Chrome.

Second we are looking at using eval() in order to put our code in a wrapper. We already do this for FF and Safari.  The real goal is to move more and more of the processing to the back end so that the need for a deployment becomes rarer.

This sounds like a lot of hoops but if you look at it from Chrome's end and the issues they have had around people doing bad things with extensions this is the price that has to be paid in order to be able to make extensions from their point of view.

Comment: This totally goes against Chrome's rules for Manifest V3 and using logic in the backend.